# Delete Sharepoint List from Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Every time I open Outlook 2007 (under Win XP) there is a Sharpoint List set up in the account settings dialog.  I remove it every time but it continues to show up.

I have also closed outlook completely down and deleted the list through the mail tool from the control panel.

Is there a way to remove it permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a workaround:

[**ISSUE - Deleted SharePoint document library re-appears in Outlook 2007**](http://blogs.msdn.com/sfellman/archive/2007/06/25/issue-deleted-sharepoint-document-library-re-appears-in-outlook-2007.aspx)